# python selenium gives me TimeoutException if i load a video

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i try to create a function that crawl a whole website.
Today a get a TimeoutException...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Entwicklung/example/crawler/crawler.py", line 46, in crawl
    driver.get(tmp)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

The TimeoutException is fire when i pass an url of a video to the driver.get() function.
My loop runs along but every driver.get() call after the TimeoutException fires a TimeoutException too. Why happens that?

```
while len(diff) > 0:
    tmp = diff.pop()
    visited.add(tmp)
    driver.get(tmp)

    elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

    for element in elements:
        href = element.get_attribute('href')
        if href is None:
            continue
        else:
            if main_url in href:
                links.add(href)

    diff = links.difference(visited)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hitting this default timeout and that's the reason you see that message.

Have you tried to use [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)? They give Selenium a little bit more time before going to the next code block.

Found this other blog: [Dealing with Selenium timeouts](https://www.garyrobinson.net/2011/06/seleniums-webdriver-python-dealing-with-script-timeouts.html). They modified the default timeout set for Selenium.

Comment: Remember that videos tend to be heavy, so Selenium might need more time to process it.

Comment: Ok i understand but i don't understand why the next driver.get("url_to_non_video") call after the TimeoutException fires a timeout too. I wouldn't like wait ten minutes or more for Selenium to process a video or other heavy sources, i would like to continue my while loop.

Comment: Or in sum i would like to ignore heavy sources that load longer than 30 seconds and continue with the next url in my diff set.

Comment: Maybe adding a counter within the method that gets the Timeout Exception. 
Whenever you call that method start the counter in 0 and add 1 every second using time or something.
If the counter reaches the 30, return something your code can handle later on. I think of an empty list, for example.

Comment: The driver.get("...") method is from selenium and i can't edit that. There is no possibility to continue the while loop easier when the exception fires? Like i said, the driver.get("...") method worked no longer if the exception fires for the first time and fire the exception dir every call.

Comment: I saw you had the try-except block before. Why don't you use it? I think of the following: When you get that Exception, put a 'continue' so your loop will go to the next iteration.

Comment: I have tried but as i mentioned earlier all method calls of driver.get(tmp) after the first TimeoutException fires a TimeoutException too and the page not loaded. This is my problem..

Comment: I think i must interrupt the driver.get() call that produces the TimeoutException to can call the function in the next iteration. But how can i interrupt the function?

Comment: Now i have found a temporary solution. If the TimeoutException fire i open a new browser window and continue the while loop in the new browser instance. For one or two links to a video is that possible but when a website linked to more videos the memory will very busy... A possibility to interrupt the WebDriver.get() function were very nice.